# Some doubts about User defined services in cloudfoundry(CF)

Tags: cloud-foundry

Are they user managed or CF managed?
And do they run external to CF?
And while using them does PaaS provision the resource or does it only supply the connection information?

Comment: Very broad and Unclear question.. Can you please be specific ? What exactly you are expecting to understand ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are they user managed or CF managed?

User provided services, as the name implies, are totally managed by the user. You run `cf cups` and provide 100% of the information that will be delivered to your application. They are very similar to using `cf set-env` to provide information via environment variables.

> And do they run external to CF?

It entirely depends. There may be nothing even to run. It all depends on what you are passing in as user provided services.

Examples:

- You could have an external database and you create a user provided service to pass in the credentials.
- You have a web service running on CF, you create a user provided service to pass in credentials to the service.

> And while using them does PaaS provision the resource or does it only supply the connection information?

There is no provisioning that occurs with a user provided service. When you run `cf cups`, you pass in any information that the app requires to connect to a preexisting service.